# PDE with distributional coefficient

Tags: partial-differential-equations, mathematical-physics, distribution-theory

I'm a undergraduate major in physics and when learning mathematical aspects of quantum physics, I run into for example this problem:

for a $1$-dim system with $\delta$-potential $$-\frac{d^2}{dx^2}\phi +  \delta (x) \phi=E\phi$$ with certain asymptotic conditions, in physics books this kind of PDEs is usually solved by ad hoc tricks, and the method of dealing with elliptic PDE doesn't work for the ill-defined multiplication.

So my question is:

> Is there a general theory for PDE with distributional coefficient?

Comment: This may not be exactly what you're asking, but there is definitely a near infinite amount of literature on how to define the operator $-\Delta +V$ for singular $V$. The book by Albeverio et al. could be an entry point to this.

Answer (score 6):

Standard methods of dealing with elliptic PDE do work: In one dimension, multiplication by $\delta(x)$ is a compact operator from $H^1$ to $H^{-1}$. So the usual variational approach works, among other things.

Comment: It won't work in two or more dimension because $H^1$ does not embed into $L^\infty$.

Comment: The question was about the 1d case. I do not think the problem has a sensible interpretation in higher dimensions.

Comment: Oh ! I missed the point.